# Signing into website with Python with hidden form fields

Tags: python

I'm trying to sign into a website via a python script but I cannot get this to work.

I'm using requests and BeautifulSoup.

This is the code I've been trying to use:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'url_here'

payload = {
    'UserName': 'username',
    'Password': 'password'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

The code above prints only the HTML for the login page, so it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Is there a way to find out what I'm missing?

Comment: The spelling must match exactly.  You're sure the username field is spelled `UserName`?  If there is a submit button, sometimes the login handlers will check for the button field as well.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I believe there are a few other fields that are being checked actually, now that I'm looking at it (though most are empty). There is one called "SRN", that appears to be randomly generated when the login page is accessed. When I go to the page in a browser, I can see the random number associated with that field, but the 'SRN' field is empty when I run a GET request on the page via python. Not sure why that is.

Comment: *Not sure why that is* -- to prevent people from doing exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Lol - solid point. I actually ended up getting it to work by ignoring that part entirely. Thanks again, you ended up pointing me in the right direction.